# How to apply new validation for a domain field on grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've this domain:

```
class Foo {
  static hasMany=[
    bars: Bar
  ]

  String name

  static constraints = {
    name(blank: false, unique: true)
  }
}
```

after inserting values to database I added another validation for bars

```
bars(nullable: false, validator: {value, object ->
            if(value.isEmpty()){
               return['bars.empty.validation.error']
            }
        })
```

now when i try to update Foo instances that were saved with no bars save is complaining on field `bars`:

```
Field error in object 'Foo' on field 'bars': rejected value [[Bar : (unsaved)]]
```

**My question** is how can I update `Foo` instances with no `bars`

Comment: Yes it is. Because when you try and update the Foo instance it's no longer valid because you have added the constraint (requirement) that it must have Bars. This is expected behavior for what you have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your custom validation to only apply to instances that don't have an `id` associated with them (indicating they are being inserted and not updated). Such as this:

```
bars(nullable: false, validator: {value, object ->
  if (object?.id) return // don't apply to previously saved instance.
  if(value.isEmpty()){
    return['bars.empty.validation.error']
  }
})
```

Comment: This would, however, allow you to later clear out the bars of a Foo that was required to have bars when it was first saved.